# Быстрое возведение матрицы в степень

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь применить быстрое возведение числа в степень на матрицу, работать работает, но считает не корректно.
Код который получился:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def Multiply(array_one, array_two, n):
    c = [[0]*len(array_one[0]) for i in range(len(array_one))]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            c[i][j] = sum(array_one[i][k]*array_two[k][j] for k in range(n))
    return c

def Power(array, n, y):
    if y == 0:
        return array
    if (y % 2) == 1:
        return Multiply(Power(array, n, y - 1 ), array, n)
    else:
        array = Power(array, n, y / 2)
        return Multiply(array, array, n)
m, n = 2, 4
b = []
a = []
for i in range(n):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        b[i].append(random.randint(1, 10))
print(b)
a = Power(b, n, m)
print(a)
```

Что получилось при выполнении этого:

Исходная матрица:

```
[[9, 8, 3, 2], 
[6, 8, 7, 2], 
[2, 7, 3, 1],
[5, 4, 3, 5]]
```

Результат выполнения кода:

```
[[53473, 66627, 40590, 18950], 
 [51235, 64233, 39199, 18223], 
 [29874, 37545, 22986, 10640], 
 [38095, 47294, 28784, 13643]]
```

В чем моя ошибка и как это исправить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При возведении матрицы в нулевую степень нужно возвращать единичную матрицу, а не исходную (которая получается при возведении в 1-ю степень). Из-за этого у вас выходит в результате возведение в [четвёртую](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B9,%208,%203,%202%5D,%20%20%5B6,%208,%207,%202%5D,%20%20%5B2,%207,%203,%201%5D,%20%5B5,%204,%203,%205%5D%5D%5E4) степень, а не во вторую.

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде получилось  :)